# Azure table storage c# with repository pattern and xUnit

Tags: c#, azure, xunit

How can I implement a repository pattern using Azure Storage and should it support xUnit test and mock objects? 
I am working on xUnit test cases and unfortunately I wasn't able to write a unit test case due to not being able to mock CloudStorageAccount and CloudTableClient.

Sample Code :-

```
public abstract class TableStorageRepository 
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public CloudStorageAccount _cloudStorageAccount;
    public CloudTableClient _tableClient;
    protected CloudTable _table;

    public TableStorageRepository (IConfiguration configuration)
    {
         _config = configuration;
         _cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse ("key");
         _tableClient = _cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient (
              new TableClientConfiguration ());
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetEntitiesAsync (TableQuery<T> query) 
    {
         _table = _tableClient.GetTableReference("Tablename");
         await _table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync ();
         TableContinuationToken token = null;
         var entities = new List<T> ();
         do 
         {
             var queryResult = await _table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync (query, token);
             entities.AddRange (queryResult.Results);
             token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
          } while (token != null);

          return entities;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First. Accept what a unittest is for. It´s for testing a single unit of your code. I`m guessing you don`t really care about persistence in this case. Since the code you are actually testing probably is further up the chain. So with that in mind - lets mock the persistence layer so you can use it some where else.

Let TableStorageRepository implement an interface.

```
ITableStorageRepository {
TableStorageRepository (IConfiguratin configuration);
Task<List<T>> GetEntitiesAsync (TableQuery<T> query);
}
```

Usage eg.:

```
#Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<ITableStorageRepository>();

mock.Setup(.... etc.

var systemUnderTest = new TheServiceImActuallyTesting(mock.Object);

#Act

var resp = systemUnderTest.GetStuff(query);

#Assert
```

Your assertions here

Comment: thanks . we are alredy done for service . i m looking for Repository

Comment: In that case. Maybe splitting the question into smaller parts would be a good starting point. The repository pattern alone is quite opinionated but you don't have to know anything about any specific tech to implement that part. MS ex. can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. Then we start talking about testing :)

Answer (score 0):

For Mocking of CloudTableClient . Please follow below snippet

var cloudTableMock = new Mock(new Uri("http://unittests.localhost.com/FakeTable")
, (TableClientConfiguration)null);

List deviceUserLinkDataList = new List();
DeviceUserLinkData deviceUserLinkData = new DeviceUserLinkData();

```
        deviceUserLinkDataList.Add(deviceUserLinkData);

        var ctor = typeof(TableQuerySegment<DeviceUserLinkData>)
            .GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetParameters().Count() == 1);
```

var mockQuerySegment = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { deviceUserLinkDataList }) as TableQuerySegment;

```
        cloudTableMock.Setup(table => table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(It.IsAny<TableQuery<DeviceUserLinkData>>(), null))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockQuerySegment));

        var cloudTableClientMock = new Mock<CloudTableClient>(new Uri("http://localhost")
            , new StorageCredentials(accountName: "blah", keyValue: "blah")
            , (TableClientConfiguration)null);  
                                                

      
        cloudTableClientMock.Setup(client => client.GetTableReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(cloudTableMock.Object);
```

Here DeviceUserLinkData  is a user Defined class and ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync returns the list of DeviceUserLinkData